# UniformGrid adding Buttons over C#

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid

I have in my WPF a UniformGrid

```
<UniformGrid Height="144" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,136,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" MaxHeight="144" MaxWidth="213" MinHeight="144" MinWidth="213" x:Name="PATH_DataGrid" Columns="7" Rows="6">
</UniformGrid>
```

and I will add some autogeneretet Buttons over C# cod to it

```
Button b = new Button();
            b.Content = "22";
            b.Width = 100;
            b.Height = 100;
```

Ho can I add the button to the UniformGrid??

```
        PATH_DataGrid`???
```

THX for you help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PATH_DataGrid.Children.Add(b)
```

That will add the button to the panel.